# compositeComponent with primefaces datatable selection does not return object

Tags: primefaces, datatable, selection, composite-component

I've made a composite component using primefaces 5.1. I want a dialog to show up, you can input a name and search the db. Then you can select one entry and the dialog closes again. My Problem ist that the selection in the dataTable always returns null...

this is the composite:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">


    <composite:interface componentType="searchCustomer">
        <composite:attribute name="customerCache" required="true"
            type="com.hji.tis.ui.cache.customer.CustomerCache" />
        <composite:attribute name="useExtendedCustomersOnly" default="false" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
            id="searchCustomerIcon" onclick="PF('searchCustomerDialog').show();" />
        <p:tooltip for="searchCustomerIcon"
            value="#{msgs['request.searchByCustomerNumber']}" />

        <p:dialog header="#{msgs['general.searchCustomer']}" resizable="false"
            draggable="false" width="500" height="450" modal="true"
            appendTo="@(body)" widgetVar="searchCustomerDialog">
            <p:panel id="searchCustomerDialogContent" style="width:100%">
                <p:panelGrid style="width:480px">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="width:60px">
                            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/userSearch.png"
                                width="50" height="50" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:100px">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msgs['general.customerName']}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:160px">
                            <p:inputText value="#{cc.custSearch_name}"
                                id="input_searchCustomerName" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
                                action="#{cc.findCustomersByName}"
                                update="searchCustomerDialogContent"
                                process="@this, input_searchCustomerName" partialSubmit="true" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="4">
                            <p:dataTable value="#{cc.filteredCustomers}" var="customer"
                                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300"
                                emptyMessage="#{msgs['general.noSelection']}"
                                selection="#{cc.selectedCustomer}" rowKey="#{customer.id}"
                                selectionMode="single">
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" />
                                <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.customerName']}"
                                    styleClass="unmarkable">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{customer.fullName}"
                                        rendered="#{!customer.extendedCustomer}" />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}"
                                        rendered="#{customer.extendedCustomer}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.address']}"
                                    styleClass="unmarkable">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="#{customer.homeAddress.address.country}, #{customer.homeAddress.address.zipCode} #{customer.homeAddress.address.city}, #{customer.homeAddress.address.street} #{customer.homeAddress.address.houseNr}" />
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="4">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" style="float:right"
                                action="#{cc.test}" process="@this, searchCustomerDialogContent"
                                partialSubmit="true" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dialog>
    </composite:implementation>
    </html>
```

and this is the Faces Component:

```
        package com.hji.tis.ui.util.customComponents;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
    import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;

    import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

    import com.hji.tis.domain.model.customer.Customer;
    import com.hji.tis.ui.cache.customer.CustomerCache;

    /**
     * NamingContainer for the custom element searchCustomer.
     * 
     * @author mayra
     *
     */
    @FacesComponent("searchCustomer")
    public class SearchCustomer extends UINamingContainer {
        private final String CUSTOMER_CACHE = "customerCache";
        private final String USER_EXTENDED_CUSTOMERS_ONLY = "useExtendedCustomersOnly";
        private final String FILTERED_CUSTOMERS = "filteredCustomers";
        private final String SELECTED_CUSTOMER = "selectedCustomer";

        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String custSearch_name;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        private Customer custSearch_selectedCustomer;

        @Override
        public void encodeBegin(FacesContext facesContext) throws IOException {
            initCustomerCache();
            initUseExtendedCustomersOnly();

            super.encodeBegin(facesContext);
        }

        public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            System.out.println(((Customer) (event.getObject())).getFullName());
        }

        /**
         * finds the customer by the name set to the _Name field. Decides wether
         * only private Customers should be returned or extended.
         */
        public void findCustomersByName() {
            this.custSearch_selectedCustomer = null;
            if (useExtendedCustomersOnly()) {
                setFilteredCustomers(getCustomerCache().findExtendedCustomerEntriesByName(custSearch_name));
            } else {
                setFilteredCustomers(getCustomerCache().findAllCustomerEntriesByName(custSearch_name));
            }
        }

        private boolean useExtendedCustomersOnly() {
            return getStateHelperValue(USER_EXTENDED_CUSTOMERS_ONLY);
        }

        private CustomerCache getCustomerCache() {
            return getStateHelperValue(CUSTOMER_CACHE);
        }

        public Customer getSelectedCustomer() {
            return (Customer) this.getStateHelper().get(SELECTED_CUSTOMER);
        }

        public void setSelectedCustomer(Customer customer) {
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!HERE THE CUSTOMER IS ALWAYS NULL
            this.getStateHelper().put(SELECTED_CUSTOMER, customer);
        }

        public List<Customer> getFilteredCustomers() {
            return (List<Customer>) this.getStateHelper().get(FILTERED_CUSTOMERS);
        }

        private void setFilteredCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
            this.getStateHelper().put(FILTERED_CUSTOMERS, customers);
        }

        /**
         * stores the customerCache in the state helper.
         */
        private void initCustomerCache() {
            CustomerCache customerCache = getAttributeValue(CUSTOMER_CACHE);
            this.getStateHelper().put(CUSTOMER_CACHE, customerCache);
        }

        private void initUseExtendedCustomersOnly() {
            String value = getAttributeValue(USER_EXTENDED_CUSTOMERS_ONLY);
            boolean boolValue = false;
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE")) {
                boolValue = true;
            } else {
                boolValue = false;
            }

            this.getStateHelper().put(USER_EXTENDED_CUSTOMERS_ONLY, boolValue);
        }

        /**
         * Return specified attribute value or otherwise the specified default if
         * it's null.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private <T> T getAttributeValue(String key) {
            return (T) this.getAttributes().get(key);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private <T> T getStateHelperValue(String key) {
            return (T) this.getStateHelper().get(key);
        }

    }
```

Maybe someone knows the reason why?

Thanks!